# Forcing extra columns to show up in pandas pivot table?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, pivot, pivot-table

Is it possible to force Pandas to include a specific set of ordered columns in a pivot table, irrespective of whether the underlying data warrants their presence? For example

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'Project': ['ProjectA', 'ProjectB', 'ProjectC'],
                   'Start Month': [2,5,9],
                   'End Month': [3,7,10],
                   'Category': ['A', 'B', 'A']
                  })
pv = pd.pivot_table(df, values='Project', index='Category', columns='Start Month', aggfunc={'Project':lambda x: "".join(x) }).fillna('')
```

produces

```
Start Month  2          5         9
Category        
A            ProjectA             ProjectC
B                       ProjectB
```

but what I want is to see columns for each of the 12 months, even if there is no data there:

```
Start Month  1  2         3  4  5        6  7  8  9         10  11  12
Category        
A               ProjectA                          ProjectC
B                               ProjectB
```

This is useful in cases where the data has an underlying natural ordering and rendering representation, such as a month-by-month calendar.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just re-index on the columns?

```
pv.reindex(columns=np.arange(1, 13), fill_value='')

Start Month 1         2  3  4         5  6  7  8         9  10 11 12
Category                                                         
A               ProjectA                           ProjectC      
B                               ProjectB
```